# Android "java.lang.NullPointerException" in set location

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

**full code** 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8e66136856136beac2fa

**warning code**

```
location.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(lng));
location.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(lat));
```

**warning message**

```
05-21 04:57:52.244: E/AndroidRuntime(2549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main<br>
05-21 04:57:52.244: E/AndroidRuntime(2549): Process: com.example.maptestiii, PID: 2549<br>
05-21 04:57:52.244: E/AndroidRuntime(2549): java.lang.NullPointerException<br>
05-21 04:57:52.244: E/AndroidRuntime(2549): <br>
at com.example.maptestiii.MainActivity$MapClickedListener.onClick(MainActivity.java:114)
```

full warning message at the button of the code url
how to solve this question?
thank you very much!!

I can change location by eclipse's Emulator Control
so i think is not the **"location null"**'s  problem

i can't do nothing so i ask here how to solve this question

thank you very much

Comment: `location` is `null`!! check the nullity before `location.setLongitude()` and `location.setLatitude()`

Comment: I can change location by eclipse's Emulator Control
so i think is not the "location null"'s problem

Comment: have you tried like @DnR suggested in answer below?

Comment: use DnR's suggested will not shot down but can't do the thing I want to do ( change location )

Comment: thats(can't change location) because the `location` is actually `null`. when you allow to change the `location` while its `null`, then there you go `NullPointerException`

Comment: I know what you mean, but in my code line 158, `location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);`    why location still null? thank you

Comment: well thats what you should ask in your question, _"Why location still null?"_ your _'thank you'_. sounds mocking. no need to be like that, I'm just trying to help. I've experienced this problem before, but mine is on windows Mobile(vb.net). how about change line 158 to `location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`?

Comment: sorry English is not my mother tongue , let you feel mocking is my bad. I try `location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` but still can't work with the same warning message. by the way, how should i say at the end and will not sounds mocking?

Comment: LOL forget about it. its probably just my bad day, assuming all people mocking me :D

Comment: Back to the question, I'm going to find out the problem since I will make my apps[currently Windows Mobile] for android soon. which I think similar like this. If you found out the problem, hope you don't mind to share it here :)

Comment: i did it!! add a line `Location location = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);` before `location.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(lng));` then can work . i am confused because i have initialize location at line 158, why i should do it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. `lng` is `null`.
2. `location`is `null`.

I haven't fully debugged your code, just a quick browse and I see that `location` is a member field and in the method where the latitude and longitude are set the `location` member fied is set in the `if() {` part, but in the `else {` part you assume that it has already been assigned.

Comment: @BobbyDigital the code crashes at the setting of `lng`. However, I've come to realize that neither `lng` nor `lat` is `null`, as the `if` checks for empty string (`""`) which would have caused a NPE if either of the two had been `null`. So the culprit seems to be `location`.

Comment: i did it! by add a line `Location location = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);` before `location.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(lng));` then can work . i am confused because i have initialize location at line 158, why i should do it again?

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution will be:

```
if(location != null){
    location.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(lng));
    location.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(lat));
}
```